# Weblogic has input localhost: 7001 which directory is in?

Tags: weblogic

Tomcat enter localhost: 8080 in webapp directory。Then the weblogic has input localhost: 7001  which directory is in?

Comment: Are you looking for where you can change the port of Weblogic Admin Server? 7001?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to know where would Weblogic keep the deployed apps.

Weblogic keeps them in $WEBLOGIC_HOME/application directory

$WEBLOGIC_HOME ---> install location of your WebLogic software